# Smoothing EdgeDetect - image processing

Tags: image-processing, smoothing

I have to make a program that analyzes the image of saw tooth and later find the function that can describe it (or just part of it). Now I have a problem with smoothing the edges detected with `EdgeDetect`. After trying some codes already posted on Stack I come out to this:

```
img = ImageRotate[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZBFz.jpg"], π/2];
smtFactor = 0.2;
img = TotalVariationFilter[ImageClip[img], 0.2, Method -> "Gaussian"]
imgSize = ImageDimensions[img];
imgClean = 
  img // Blur[#, 2] & // Binarize // ColorNegate // Erosion[#, 1] &;
edges = EdgeDetect[imgClean, Method -> Metoda] ;
Koord = Map[# &, GatherBy[PixelValuePositions[edges, 1], First] ];
L1 = ListPlot[Koord, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, 
  Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Edges", 
  PlotRange -> {{1, imgSize[[1]]}, {0, imgSize[[2]]}}]
n = Length[Koord];
vars = Array[y, n];
constraints = 
  Array[Koord[[#]] - smtFactor <= y[#] <= Koord[[#]] + smtFactor &, n];
smoothness = Total[Differences[vars, 2]^2];
{fit, sol} = FindMinimum[{smoothness, constraints}, vars];
smoothKoord = vars /. sol;
ListPlot[smoothKoord, 
 Prolog -> {Red, Opacity[0.5], 
   constraints /. {y0_ <= y[x_] <= y1_ -> Line[{{x, y0}, {x, y1}}]}}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> "Edges to be smoothed", 
 PlotRange -> {{1, imgSize[[1]]}, {0, imgSize[[2]]}}]
Show[img, L1]
```

Output:   [image: result]

In some cases, it works, but it does not describe the bottom part [image: error] (Output form a bit different code)
I don't know how to solve the error. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Up to now, this is only an extended comment.

The problem is that the sawtooth (at the current orientation) is not a graph of a function: some x-values have multiple y-values. So you should not use a graph of a function as ansatz but a more general curve.

When using a list of points in the plane as unknown, you should consider the following as regularization; it's a not so untypical discretization of the Euler-Bernoulli bending energy.

```
getEulerBernoulli = Quiet@Block[{P, PP, X, Y, rX, rY, nX, d, nY, U, V},
    d = 2;
    PP = Table[P[[i, j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, d}];
    X = PP[[2]] - PP[[1]];
    Y = PP[[3]] - PP[[2]];
    rX = Sqrt[X.X];
    rY = Sqrt[Y.Y];
    nX = X/rX;
    nY = Y/rY;
    U = nX - nY;
    V = nX + nY;
    P \[Function] Evaluate[Together[8 U.U/V.V/(rX + rY)]]
    ];

vars = Transpose[{Array[x, {n}], Array[y, n]}];
smoothness = Total[getEulerBernoulli /@ Partition[vars, 3]];
```

The Euler-Bernoulli bending energy of a curve $\gamma \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is given by

$$\mathscr{E}(\gamma) =  \frac{1}{2}\int_a^b |\kappa_\gamma(t)|^2\, |\gamma'(t)|\, \operatorname{d} t,$$

where $\kappa_\gamma \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is the curvature vector of $\gamma$.

The idea of this discretization for a polygonal line $p = (p_0,\dotsc,p_n)$ is basically to replace the integral by a Riemann sum and the curvature by turning angles $\alpha_i = \measuredangle(p_i-p_{i-1},p_{i+1}-p_i)$:

$$\mathscr{E}_n(p) =  \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{\alpha_i}{\ell_i} \right)^2 \, \ell_i = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{\alpha_i^2}{\ell_i},$$

where $\ell_i = \frac{1}{2}( |p_i-p_{i-1}| + |p_{i+1}-p_{i}|)$ is the average of the length of two consecutive edges.

If $n$ is not too large, Mathematica's `FindMinimum` may find a (local) minimizer in reasonable time.

Moreover, you will have to replace the constraints...

The price for this all is that the optimization problem is changed a quadratic one (quadratic objective with linear inequality constraints) to a nonlinear one. Thus, is might be a better idea to separate the detected edges into 2 or more groups so that each of them can be approximated by a (rotated) function graph and to apply your method onto each of these groups.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was somehow thinking in the same direction, to split the curve in 3 parts (like this - (https://imgur.com/fF7SbXZ). But I have difficulties splitting the list `Koord = Map[# &, GatherBy[PixelValuePositions[edges, 1], First] ];`. I think that by using `Max[Koord]` the code would find the tip of the tooth. But I was unable to successfully manipulate the list. Because if it is in MatrixForm it has unequal subs. Can you please help me? Also, thank you for mentioning EulerBernoulli, I will have deeper look in it later.